# Flex4: how to create the view states in as class (code-behind)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

According to this document from Adobe [Create and apply view states](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf63611-7ffa.html) is `<s:State/>` a state object.
How to create the view states in code-behind ActionScript class?

Comment: Actionscript doesn't have code-behind.  Your MXML and AS3 code are in separate classes.

Comment: The AS class is the code behind.

Comment: That's not code behind.  It's a separate class.

Comment: Here is the definition of "code-behind": "(computing, programming) A technique in web design (specifically Microsoft ASP.NET) in which the web page and back-end source code are stored in separate files, allowing web designers and programmers to work independently." - From [link](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/code-behind). In my case, the MXML is the design and the AS class is the logic. So it is a code-behind.

Comment: Your MXML file is a full class on its own.  You might as well write MyDesign.mxml and MyCodeBehind.mxml (or MyDesign.as and MyCodeBehind.as).  There's no dividing line that makes one "front-end" and the other "back-end", unlike code-behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a simple solution, and I don't have to declare the states using skinning architecture. I don't even to declare the states in my ApplicationClass which extends WindowedApplication.
The solution is: declare the states only in the Main.MXML and by all means with the right namespace, in my case it should be "custom".
Here is the Main.MXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<custom:ApplicationClass xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                         xmlns:custom="components.*">
    <custom:states>  
        <s:State name="loginState"/> 
        <s:State name="infoState"/>
    </custom:states>

    <s:Panel id="loginPanel" title="Login" includeIn="loginState" />

</custom:ApplicationClass>
```

I only want to change between different Panels, so this method works well for me. There are certainly other cases, in which the states need to be declared in skinning.
I have got this solution form this link: [Error: Could not resolve  to a component implementation.](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/782910)